# How do the different sizes of modules compare to eachother?

Tags: space-pirates-and-zombies

Is there an equivalency between some number of small modules and medium/large/huge?

Does 3 small modules equal, in terms of effect/damage, a large perhaps? 2 a medium?

Perhaps it scales instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Module damage scales with size by following relation:

```
Weapon Size Damage
Small       100%
Medium      150%
Large       225%
Huge        337.5%
```

Two medium weapons is better than one large. Double turret increase damage but decrease range.

Source: [SPAZ wiki](http://spacepiratesandzombies.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Damage#Damage_Per_Hit)

Answer (score 2):

Two modules of one size will do more damage than a module of the next size up, but will have a shorter range.